# How to add dots in Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, marker, mapbox

I am using mapbox.js and mapbox.css. Mapbox has pretty good API to add [default markers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/single-marker/) and [custom markers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-marker/), but how do I add dots that I can style freely. Here is an [example](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/assets/pages/zoom-styling-3.png). It is constructed from Mapbox TileMill.

The custom marker API only supports loading custom image so that I cannot style it on the fly. The Mapbox TileMill is a GUI which is not consistent with my development environment. I found a promising example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/yhahn/4220184), but the version of mapbox.js it uses is too old and the current version doesn't have those APIs.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [an example with the current Mapbox.js library that should work well for this use case](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/scaled-markers/).